# Problem running mongodb container with docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '3.7'

services:
  flask:
      build: .
      depends_on:
        - mongo
      ports:
        - 5000:5000
      volumes:
        - ./app:/app
      

  mongo:
      image: mongo:latest
      ports:
        - 27017:27017
      volumes:
        - ./dump:/dump
        - ./datos_db:/data/db
```

Im getting this error:

```
mongo_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2020-11-28T00:58:25.647+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}                        mongo_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2020-11-28T00:58:25.648+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}                                                          mongo_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2020-11-28T00:58:25.648+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}                                                                                                          mongo_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2020-11-28T00:58:25.649+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":1,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"8cbdb13db521"}}                                                                                                                    mongo_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2020-11-28T00:58:25.649+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.2","gitVersion":"15e73dc5738d2278b688f8929aee605fe4279b0e","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu1804","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}                                                                            mongo_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2020-11-28T00:58:25.649+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"18.04"}}}                                           mongo_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2020-11-28T00:58:25.649+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"net":{"bindIp":"*"}}}}                                        mongo_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2020-11-28T00:58:25.667+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=5829M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}                                                                        mongo_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2020-11-28T00:58:26.229+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":17,"message":"[1606525106:229830][1:0x7f24edc4fac0], connection: __posix_open_file, 808: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists"}}                                                  mongo_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2020-11-28T00:58:26.242+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"unexpected file WiredTiger.wt found, renamed to WiredTiger.wt.15"}}     mongo_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2020-11-28T00:58:26.286+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":1,"message":"[1606525106:286758][1:0x7f24edc4fac0], connection: __posix_open_file, 808: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted"}}                                       mongo_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2020-11-28T00:58:26.345+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":17,"message":"[1606525106:345262][1:0x7f24edc4fac0], connection: __posix_open_file, 808: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists"}}                                                  mongo_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2020-11-28T00:58:26.380+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"unexpected file WiredTiger.wt found, renamed to WiredTiger.wt.16"}}     mongo_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2020-11-28T00:58:26.382+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":1,"message":"[1606525106:382092][1:0x7f24edc4fac0], connection: __posix_open_file, 808: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted"}}                                       mongo_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2020-11-28T00:58:26.396+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":17,"message":"[1606525106:396022][1:0x7f24edc4fac0], connection: __posix_open_file, 808: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists"}}                                                  mongo_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2020-11-28T00:58:26.406+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"unexpected file WiredTiger.wt found, renamed to WiredTiger.wt.17"}}     mongo_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2020-11-28T00:58:26.407+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":1,"message":"[1606525106:407493][1:0x7f24edc4fac0], connection: __posix_open_file, 808: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted"}}                                       mongo_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2020-11-28T00:58:26.409+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22347,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version. This may be due to an unsupported upgrade or downgrade."}                                                                                                              mongo_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2020-11-28T00:58:26.409+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":28595,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Terminating.","attr":{"reason":"1: Operation not permitted"}}                                                  mongo_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2020-11-28T00:58:26.409+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":28595,"file":"src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp","line":1123}}                                                                                                                mongo_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2020-11-28T00:58:26.409+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

Im using windows linux subsystem (wls) to run docker-compose build and docker-compose run, then i get this error.

Im getting:

```
"container_name exited with code 14"
```

Comment: i will suggest using `unix/linux` based operating systems to try out `docker` as docker recommends using containers only on those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently WSL+Docker can't work with mongo.

I didn't find any way to make it work, i think is just not compatible.